# HTML/CSS3 - I added a shape into my nav bar, and it messed up the alignment or my wrapper

Tags: html, css

So I have started to mess around with responsive html. But anyways, that's not really the issue. The issue is after i added this parallelogram shape, it messed up the contents of my wrapper. I tried using z-index to make it so the nav bar appears over the wrapper, but then It didn't work when I set my wrapper to relative, it worked when i set it to absolute/fixed and z-index -1. I'm just trying to get my wrapper to be aligned in the center while having the parallelogram shape in the nav bar. Because right now, my 2 column layout is being messed up because of the shape.(I suck at explaining, but if you look at my site on jsfiddle, I think you can get the idea) Thanks!

http://jsfiddle.net/RgKaQ/

heres something I've tried

```
nav {
    height: 40px;
    width: 100%;
    background: #33FF00;
    font-size: 11pt;
    font-family: 'PT Sans', Arial, sans-serif;
    font-weight: bold;
    position: relative;
    border-bottom: 2px solid #339900;
    z-index : 1;

}
.wrapper {
    width: 800px;
    margin: 0 auto;
       /* position: relative; doesn't work*/
        position: fixed; /*works but it makes it not aligned in the center*/
    z-index: -1;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The id #swank (which is taller than the nav) is causing the problems. Use position:absolute; for the nav and add margin to .wrapper. Like this. http://jsfiddle.net/RgKaQ/4/

```
nav {
position:absolute;
top: 0;
}
.wrapper {
margin: 40px auto 0 auto;
overflow:auto;
}
```

Comment: Perfect, that fixed my problem! Ah I see the absolute vs relative now. Thank you so much! I would vote up but I can't ;).

Comment: I also had a question though, when I resize the window for the responsiveness, it the nav bar just floats right over the content.

Comment: The .wrapper has width of 800px, so its will not be really responsive. For that you should make it 100% with a max-width: 800px; If you wish to lock it at 800px, consider turning off the responsive nav, as it will just confuse. If you want .wrapper to move up and down according to the nav height (responsive), place the content of nav in a div, that way #swank will not cause troubles.

Answer (score 0):

Try to use the  position this absolute if you want to chage the css for nav bar make hte changes in nav bar css not in wrapper ..

```
.wrapper {
width: 800px;
margin: 0 auto;
   /* position: relative; doesn't work*/
   /* position: fixed; works but it makes it not aligned in the center*/
     position:absolute;
z-index: -1;
```

}

Comment: It makes it aligned to the left, but I need it to be aligned in the middle.

Comment: nav {
    height: 40px;
    width: auto;
    background: #33FF00;
    font-size: 11pt;
    font-family: 'PT Sans', Arial, sans-serif;
    font-weight: bold;
    position: relative;
    border-bottom: 2px solid #339900;
    z-index : 1;

} try to set margin from left side for adjust in middle

Comment: also use the previoush code and add display:inline-block  or text-align-center; properties of css

Comment: I don't believe that did anything at all. The Nav bar is fine, but you see how the body is messed up? those 2 divs should be right besides one another, but the alignment is messed up. ***** Trying your edit & it didn't do anything.

Comment: in this picture http://i.imgur.com/gcqse7V.png see how the login box is above the content, it should be side by side, but the parallelogram  shape is messing it up.